# Testing existence of variable that is explicitly passed to a function in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to test for the existence of a variable that is explicitly passed to a function. The task is proving trickier than I expected. The problem is that I want the default argument to be `NULL`, and I also want users to be able to explicitly pass a `NULL` value. But if users instead try to pass a variable that doesn't exist –– for example, if they misspell a variable when calling the function –– it too will be NULL in the function, and in this case, I will want my function to stop with an error.

Here is a simple example. It uses the `iris` dataset, which has a `Species` variable but not a `species` variable. With one exception, described below, the function here does what I want. But it is clunky and it doesn't explicitly test for existence, which worries me. Is there a better way?

```
data(iris)
myFunc <- function (x = NULL) {
  if (!missing(x)) {  # if x was explicitly passed by user
    xName <- deparse(match.call()$x)
    if (xName != 'NULL' && is.null(x)) {
      stop("The variable doesn't seem to exist.")
    }
    else print("x was explicitly passed, and there are no problems.")
  }
  else print("x was not passed by the user.")
} 

myFunc(x = NULL)          # "x was explicitly passed, and there are no problems."
myFunc(x = iris$Species)  # "x was explicitly passed, and there are no problems."
myFunc(x = iris$species)  # "The variable doesn't seem to exist."
y <- iris$species
myFunc(y)                 # "The variable doesn't seem to exist."
```

Two further notes:

- I would like `z <- NULL; myFunc(z)` to return "x was explicitly passed, and there are no problems." Instead, it returns an error ("The variable doesn't seem to exist."). I can probably get around this by adding code that checks for the existence of `z` in the calling environment—something like `exists(z, envir = parent.frame())`)—but is there a better way?
- I would like to use `exists()` to test for the existence of the `x` object, but it doesn't seem flexible enough. For example, `exists(iris)` works, but `exists(iris$Species)` returns `FALSE` even though I'd like it to return `TRUE` for this purpose.

Comment: Why does the user need to be able to pass `NULL` explicitly? And does that need to be different than not specifying a value, which you could easily test with `missing`? Would it work if they used `NA` instead?

Comment: I do think `if ('x' %in% names(match.call()))` is an awkward way to write `if(!missing(x))`...

Comment: It looks to me that you are interested in checking whether a dataset contains a given column, rather than checking whether a variable exists. For instance, `myFunc(aaa)` returns an error stating `aaa object not found`. From your description, I'd say that you want the error to be `The variable doesn't seem to exist.`

Comment: @Gregor, thank you. You're right: using `names(match.call())` is awkward, and `!missing(x)` seems better for this purpose. I'll edit the question. As for why the user should be able to pass NULL explicitly: sometimes users want to spell out the arguments that they pass to functions, and in this case, I want them to be able to do so.

Comment: @nicola - thank you. If the user tries to pass a column name, then yes, I want to check for the existence of that column. On the other hand, if the user simply passes a variable name (say, `species` instead of `iris$species`), I want to check the existence of that variable.

Comment: So, `iris$a` is `NULL`, `identical(iris$a, NULL)` returns `TRUE`. But you want to be able to tell the difference between them. That's probably doable, with `deparse` or something. What if they set `y <- iris$a` and `z <- NULL`. How do you want `myFunc(y)` and `myFunc(z)` to behave?

Comment: @Gregor, thank you again. You've got it right: I want to distinguish between the two cases in your first two sentences. As for your last two examples, the tricky one is `z <- NULL; myFunc(z)`. In this case, the function in the example stops with an error. But I would rather have it return ""x was explicitly passed, and there are no problems." I've updated my original post on this point.